# Play wave file every 500 ms

Tags: android

i got this class here:

```
public class ViewBeat1 extends MasterView {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            stream = getAssets().open("some_gif.gif");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GifMovieView view = new GifMovieView(this, stream);

        setContentView(view);
        run();
    }

    public void run() {

        // Get the ringtone

        int milliseconds = 0;
        final SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        final int loaded = sp.load(this, R.raw.beat, 1);

        boolean played = false;


        while (milliseconds < 300000) {
            if (milliseconds >= 20000 && !played) {
                sp.stop(loaded);
                sp.release();
                played = true;
                playSong(this.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase(),
                        View6.class.getName(), 4000);
                finish();
            } else if (milliseconds <= 20000) {
                try {
                    sp.play(loaded, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    milliseconds += 500;


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.v("out of the thread", e.getMessage().toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The MasterView extends from Activity and just does some stuff most likely not needed here.
The GifMovieView sets a gif animation and puts it into the  Contentview.

Now i want to play this 500ms long wave file every 500 ms, kind of like a fast heartbeat (120 bpm). 
Somehow when i do it like this it doesn't work properly and the app kind of doesn't respond anymore. Does anybody have a better solution to achieve this?

Cheers for your help already - The StackOverflow Community is the best!

Comment: Try using your code in a handler with `postDelayed`

Comment: Could you show me how that would look like? Because i tried and it didn't work properly.

Comment: **onCreate()** isn't like **main()** in a single-threaded application. You can't just keep executing forever. All Activity methods which run in the main thread are expected to do their job and get out. If you want to do something that takes time, you need to run it in a separate thread, or do it with a handler as JuniKim suggests.

Comment: That is to say, **never** sleep in the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your app becomes unresponsive since you never return from your onCreate method!

Try creating a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and posting to it automatically every 500 milliseconds. Something like the following, perhaps

```
public class ViewBeat1 extends MasterView {
    private SoundPool mSoundPool;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable mPlaySoundRunnable;
    private Runnable mFinishRunnable;
    private int mSoundId;
    private int mPlayCount;
    private long mFinishTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        try {
            stream = getAssets().open("some_gif.gif");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        setContentView(new GifMovieView(this, stream));

        mSoundPool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        mHandler = new Handler();

        mPlaySoundRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mPlayCount++;
                mSoundPool.play(mSoundId, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);

                if (mPlayCount < 40) {
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mPlaySoundRunnable, 500L);
                }
            }
        };

        mFinishRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mSoundPool.stop(mSoundId);
                mSoundPool.release();
                playSong(Activity.this.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase(), View6.class.getName(), 4000);
                finish();
            }
        };

        mSoundId = mSoundPool.load(this, R.raw.beat, 1);
        if (mSoundId > 0) {
            mHandler.post(mPlaySoundRunnable);
        }

        mFinishTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 30000L;
        mHandler.postAtTime(mFinishRunnable, mFinishTime);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mFinishRunnable);
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mPlaySoundRunnable);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mHandler.postAtTime(mFinishRunnable, mFinishTime);
        if (mPlayCount < 40) {
            mHandler.post(mPlaySoundRunnable);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do that in the gui thread, since it blocks nearly everything. That is the reason, why your app does not respond anymore.

Start a new thread like this

```
public class ViewBeat1 extends MasterView implements Runnable {
    ...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...
        // instead of calling run() directly, start in new thread
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: My "ViewBeat1" extends from "MasterView" and this extends from "Activity". This Activity "ViewBeat" gets called by another Activity with an Intentn. Some how i get an error when i use your technique.